# Define the function $H:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ by $H(x)=\int_{-x}^{x}[f(t)+f(-t)]dt\forall x$ Find $H''(x)$.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, derivatives

Suppose that the function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is differentiable. Define the function $H:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ by $$H(x)=\int_{-x}^{x}[f(t)+f(-t)]dt\qquad\forall x$$ Find $H''(x)$.

Proof:

$\begin{align*}
H(x)&=\int_{-x}^{x}[f(t)+f(-t)]dt=\int_{0}^{x}[f(t)+f(-t)]dt+\int_{-x}^{0}[f(t)+f(-t)]dt\\
H'(x)&=(f(x)+f(-x))+(f(-x)+f(x))=2f(x)+2f(-x)
\end{align*}$

We have: $H''(x)=2f'(x)-2f'(-x)$

---

Can someone check the solution? I am not sure I apply the second fundamental theorem of calculus correctly or not. From the theorem, $$\frac{d}{dx}\left(\int_{a}^{x}f\right)=f(x)$$ So if $F(x)=\int_{0}^{x}f(-t)dt$, then $F'(x)=f(-x)$.

Comment: You missed a minus sign in the last step, because $\frac{d}{dx}f(-x)=-f'(-x)$. The rest is fine. You could also have used the fact that the integrand is even to write from the beginning $\int_{-x}^x[f(t)+f(-t)]dt=2\int_0^x[f(t)+f(-t)]dt$

Comment: @Marcel Fixed, but how do I know $f$ is even.

Comment: $f$ doesn't need to be even, but the combination $f(t)+f(-t)$ always is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup, this looks fine. You could have also stated that the function g(t)= f(t)+f(-t) is an even function so $\int_{-x}^xg(t) dt = 2 \int_{0}^x g(t) dt$. But that is just another way of writing what you already have.

Comment: Just saw this posted in the comment section.